# Sum a series of series where each value increments by one

Tags: number-theory, summation

Can anyone suggest an elegant way to sum a series of numbers like this:

```
    (1, 2, 3, 4)
    (2, 3, 4, 5)
    (3, 4, 5, 6)
    (4, 5, 6, 7)
```

That is for $n$ sets of $d$ numbers, what is the total of all numbers?

For example in the series above, the total should be 64

Comment: You want a closed formula?

Comment: Does your first set always start by 1?

Comment: People are answering the generalization suggested by your example. Is this what you want or is your question exactly as you put it: `"That is for n sets of d numbers, what is the total of all numbers?"`?

Comment: I think we need more clarification on what you mean by "like this". Are you only interested in sets of numbers in which the rows start at 1, increment within each row by 1, and increment between rows by 1?  Or are you also interested in more general cases?

Comment: It happens to be the set always starts at $1$ but the general responses have been interesting too (i.e. @mweiss)

Answer (score 1):

For n sets of d numbers, there must be an average number. If all of the rows increment by 1 then you could just take the average of the two corners, top left and bottom right to get the average for all spots.

Example:

Average of $1$ and $7$ (rows+columns-1) is $4$ (which is always $(n+d-1+1)/2$)

$4$ (average) times $4$ (rows) times $4$(columns) is $64$

So the total is $\frac{n+d}{2}*n*d$ if it always increments by one for ever row and column and it starts at one at the top left corner.

Comment: @AJStas Why? The formula is "symmetric" in that columns and rows are arbitrary and could be switched without change. Your formula makes it different when you do. Can you explain why you think that to be correct?

Comment: You're right, I didn't realize you forced it to start at $1$.

Comment: THanks this is a really handy answer

Answer (score 1):

If you pair the $n$th number in the array, counting from the top left, with the corresponding number in the array counting from the bottom right, the total is always constant (in this example, we have $1+7=2+6=3+5=4+4=2+6= \cdots = 8$).  In an array with $n$ rows of $d$ numbers the number of such pairs will be $nd/2$.

Comment: and the value of each pair is $n+d$, so you get $(n+d) * n * d /2$.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if we're supposed to assume that in every case the first row starts with $1$, that each row increments by $1$, or that each column increments by $1$.  (IOW I don't know whether those are *accidental* features of the example or *essential* ones.)  But as long as the rows increment by a constant and the columns increment by a constant (not necessarily the same one as for the rows) the approach I described will work.

Comment: So an $n \times n$ arrangement sums to $n^3$. That's interesting actually.

Comment: @mweiss Thats a good point to consider. The good thing is that even  with just the explanation for the 1-step case, it is relatively to derive the n-step versions

Comment: @mweiss You're forgetting about the identical diagonal numbers down the middle

Comment: @Imray Not sure what you mean by saying I'm "forgetting" about them.  Because in your example the rows and columns both increment by 1, you always have $a_{n,m+1}=a_{n+1,m}=a_{n,m}+1$. I don't see why that's relevant.  In general if the increment were $k$ within a row and $j$ between rows you'd have $a_{n,m+1}=a_{n,m}+k$ and $a_{n+1,m}=a_{n,m}+j$.

Comment: @mweiss , you said that for the rows it isnt necessary that the increment is constant, so I've tried one example, but I can get the answer right.. Can you help me out for a set of series like this one? {(13, 19, 36), (18, 25, 33), (24, 32, 41)} Both the columns and lines have a different increment, that is equal to the previous column/line + 1

Comment: @BrunoCasteleiro I didn't say that "it isn't necessary that the increment is constant".  On the contrary, I said that "as long as the rows increment by a constant and the columns increment by a constant (not necessarily the same one as for the rows) the approach... will work."  In your example neither the rows *nor* the columns increment by constants, so you will need some other method.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstanding.. But, as long as I find a constant relation between the numbers, I can work on an approach like the one you did right? I know its possible for the series I showed, I just can't get there..

Comment: My approach *explicitly* relies on the fact that the increments with each row, and between each row, are both constants.

Comment: Allright, tell me then.. if I make the difference of the next number in the line or column, I get a set of differences with constant increment.. For example, for the series {(1,3,6), (2,5,9)}, 3-1=2 and 6-3=2.. and 5-2=3 and 9-5=4 for the second serie. And if I difference this results, I will have constant increment for columns.. Can I reach now an answer for the sum with your method?

Comment: @BrunoCasteleiro I would post that as a new question. It is sufficiently different from this one that it deserves its own answers.

Comment: Thanks, I just did it.
Here you have the [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1817648/summation-of-numbers-without-constant-increment) in the case you have some thoughts you want to share.